# TFS - Find all change sets connected to a task

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are using TFS 2008 / Visual Studio 2008

We are trying to merge all code related to a task. I understand from other questions here that you can only merge change sets not tasks.

Question then is how do I find all changesets connected to a task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is shown in the UI, open the task, all the associated changesets are shown in the links tab.

Comment: What I'd love to be able to do is find all the change-sets assigned to a task, and then see on one screen all the files effected, and be able to view the differences between those files across the total set of changes. Anyone know how?!

Comment: @JonH That's really a new question. The TFS API makes this possible but would require coding: open task, iterate through associated changesets, distinct merge the file changes.

Comment: Ok; asked.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333061/tfs-viewing-total-changes-for-all-files-in-all-change-sets-associated-with-a-wo