# TFS: Viewing total changes for all files in all change-sets associated with a work item

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Has anyone come across a way of searching - maybe using tfpt searchcs - of listing all the files that would changed as a result of all the change-sets that are attached to a work item in TFS?

THEN I'd like to see the differences between the first and the last change-set in each case so I can view the sum of differences in the file.

Why? I have a work item with about 20 change-sets. I don't want to see the narrative/thinking/whatever. I just want to see what changed and how.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly display all info just through a query in GUI.
You may need to use the **comapre** for each file in the workitem. Find the file in source control, use the Changeset type to compare, select the first changeset and the last changeset in workitem. It would lists the total changes of this file during the work item.
[image]

Otherwise, you may need to use API to list all changes of all files together.